# Elasticsearch, the same query bring different results

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, devtools

I have some issue with the Elasticsearch query

once I want to return only max 3 suggestions and the other time brings all suggestions.

the difference between the queries is num of size, once is default 5 and the second time is like 500.

running on dev tools in Kibana

```
POST ja-search-data-prod/_search 
{
    "suggest": {
         "promotion-suggest": {
              "prefix": "1.8",
              "completion": {
                  "field": "promoSuggest",
                  "size": 5
              }
          }
    }
}


POST ja-search-data-prod/_search 
    {
        "suggest": {
             "promotion-suggest": {
                  "prefix": "1.8",
                  "completion": {
                  "field": "promoSuggest",
                  "size": 500
              }
        }
    }
```

the result is :

size = 500

[image]

size = 5

[image]

Comment: so whats the issue?

Comment: looks like you have max 3 suggestions only for your query, hence both the query bring all the suggestions which are `3` and less than `5` and `500`

Comment: Please read https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-from-size.html for more info

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja, the issue is also if the size is 5 need to bring all 3 suggestions and this brings only 2 when size is 5.
also, I know this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-from-size.html this is not help

Comment: ok, so overall you have 3 suggestion and these comes when size is 500? can you also pass from 0 and provided your suggested docunents in your question >?

Comment: right, it is not different, if I pass from only if the size is big is return all the suggestions

Comment: this may help you to understand, look at this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-suggesters-completion.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213015/discussion-between-opster-elasticsearch-ninja-and-omer-cohen).